# What url to reach "/phone" in an Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

what url should I use to reach the "/phone" part from the routing? I am trying this `http://localhost:8888/workspace/AngA/phones` but the page is blank. Or maybe the url is correct, and I forgot something else.

Here is the whole code (2 html pages for the view, 2 js pages) :

```
//in home.html
<h1>home</h1>

<p>
    <a href="/phones/1">Add a {{ test }}</a>
</p>

----

//in index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view>hello</div>

</body>
</html>

----

//in app.js
'use strict';

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }
]);

----

//in controllers.js

'use strict';

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'age';
});

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams){

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified html5mode so to access that page you would do something like this instead:

`http://localhost:8888/workspace/AngA/#/phones`

Comment: Thanks, so I keep having "hello" as written in "index.html", but I don't get "home" from the "home.html" page. The url with "#/phones" shows exactly the same as "AngA/index.html"...